# Отправка JSON-данных из HTML form

Tags: html, json

Сделал на Flask декоратор, который должен принимать JSON-строку из html form.

```
@app.route('/processjson', methods=['POST'])
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    return jsonify(data)
```

Через Постман проверил POST запросом, отправив JSON-строку. Все работает.
Однако, отправляя саму форму из клиента, получаю:

> 400 Bad Request: Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Получается, `form` генерирует неверный формат.

Вот form:

```
<form action="/processjson" enctype="application/json" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Bender">
    <input type="submit" value="TEST">
</form>
```

`request.headers['Content-Type']` возвращает `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

Задача состоит в том, что я должен получать из form JSON-строку, а после неких операций отправлять JSON-строку в ту же форму.

Comment: Браузерные формы не поддерживают json

Comment: https://darobin.github.io/formic/specs/json/ а что насчет этого скажете?

Comment: Скажу то, что наличие каких-то там DRAFT-почеркушек в интернете не отменяет того, что в 2018 году браузерые формы не поддерживают json (хотя почеркушка хорошая, да)

Comment: Понятно. Тогда хотел бы попросить совет. Я написал конвертер чисел(работает с римскими и арабскими числами). И вот пункт из задания: "обмен данными между клиентской и серверной частями происходит с использованием формата JSON". Как вы себе это представляете?

Comment: Во-первых, «клиентская часть» это совсем не обязательно браузер (если явно не указано в задании). Во-вторых, в браузерах можно джаваскриптом, не используя формы, отправлять абсолютно произвольные данные, в том числе json

Comment: В моем случае - нужно создать одностраничное веб-приложение. Явно указано. Получается, выход - задействовать JS? Только так?

Comment: Под «одностраничным веб-приложением» почти наверняка подразумевается термин SPA, под которым почти всегда подразумевается написание почти всего на JS (традиционно с использованием какого-нибудь React, Vue или Angular), в котором можно в том числе отправлять AJAX-запросы на сервер с json-данными (с помощью XMLHttpRequest или fetch, второй предпочтительнее). Вот, ключевые слова для гугла я вам дал :)

Comment: Премного благодарен!

Comment: Хороший вариант, но можно ли как-то сделать список словарей, где словарь это строка таблицы
Примерно
|ID|KEY|NAME|
({id:1, 'key':'ключ', 'name':имя}, {id:2, 'key':'ключ', 'name':имя} {id:3, 'key':'ключ', 'name':имя})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Браузерные формы не поддерживают `application/json`. И, похоже, никогда не будут поддерживать:

> [Осторожно! Эта спецификация не поддерживается, и HTML Working Group не хочет поддерживать её в будущем.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/)

Можно отправлять запросы с `application/json` джаваскриптом. В самых простейших key/value случаях можно просто пройтись по FormData и собрать все ключики в объект, который потом закодировать в json и отправить:

```js
document.getElementById('benderform').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);


function submitForm(event) {
    // Отменяем стандартное поведение браузера с отправкой формы
    event.preventDefault();

    // event.target — это HTML-элемент form
    let formData = new FormData(event.target);

    // Собираем данные формы в объект
    let obj = {};
    formData.forEach((value, key) => obj[key] = value);
    
    // Собираем запрос к серверу
    let request = new Request(event.target.action, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(obj),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });
    
    // Отправляем (асинхронно!)
    fetch(request).then(
        function(response) {
            // Запрос успешно выполнен
            console.log(response);
            // return response.json() и так далее см. документацию
        },
        function(error) {
            // Запрос не получилось отправить
            console.error(error);
        }
    );

    // Код после fetch выполнится ПЕРЕД получением ответа
    // на запрос, потому что запрос выполняется асинхронно,
    // отдельно от основного кода
    console.log('Запрос отправляется');
}
```

```html
<form action="/processjson" id="benderform">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Bender">
  <input type="submit" value="TEST">
</form>
```

(Конечно, в реальности всё должно выглядеть не так топорно, как в этом примере (и вообще этот пример не работает, потому что в сниппетах Stack Overflow не предусмотрено тестирование ajax-запросов), но направление для дальнейших действий я дал.)

Документация: [FormData](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-forms#formdata), [Fetch](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch), [async/await](https://habr.com/company/ruvds/blog/414373/), [XMLHttpRequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest) (если нужна поддержка старых браузеров)